# EXCEL Search of multiple possible strings of text

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking to be able to process a large set of data and and find a set of predefined words in a string and return an alternate if found.. I have found i can do this individually with multiple FIND or SEARCH functions inside an IFS statement.. i want to include an OR in there though so i don't have to report as much... EG

Data:
Hello World
Hi World
Goodbye World
Bye World

I basically want to just return "Welcome" if either Hello or Hi are found in a cell

I know i can do it with htis: =IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Hello",[@Column1])),"Welcome",(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Hi",[@Column1]))),"Welcome",TRUE,"")

But would like a shorter way, since in reality my data set is much larger. I tried this: =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(OR([@Column1]="Hello",[@Column1]="HI"),"Welcome","")),"")
but just get a false response

also, want to keep it out of macros

Comment: Try this =IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND({"Hello","Hi"},[@Column1]))),"Welcome","")

Comment: @bosco_yip - oops - saw your comment as soon as I answered. Same idea.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick - Nice, basically I prefer using "Search" rather than "Find".

Comment: Note also that `FIND()` is case sensitive whereas `SEARCH()` is not.

Comment: Thank you - and also appreciate the added info that about the difference in FIND and SEARCH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
=IF( OR( ISNUMBER( SEARCH( {"Hello","Hi"}, [@Column1]) ) ), "Welcome", "" )
```